# iFrames Application for facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe

Please can anybody suggest me a good free facebook iFrames application which can allow me add atleast three tabs to the facebook fan page. In addition, is there any way to preview without going the fan page live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any application (when added to a page) will result in a tab.  It all depends what application you want there.
Pages can be in an "unpublished" state where only the administrator can see it.
Go to "edit page" and in the "Manage Permissions" tab you'll see the very first setting allows you to "unpublish" the page.

Comment: Thnx mate for your kind help. Happy coding.